# Restore snapshot to GCP volume using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have some working code that creates snapshots of disks attached to an existing server in GCP:

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("mycreds.json")
  project     = var.project
  region      = var.region
}

data "google_compute_image" "sqlserverimage" {
  family  = var.image_family
  project = var.project
}

data "google_compute_instance" "sql_instance" {
  name = var.instance_name
  project = var.project
  zone = var.zone
}

output "instance" {
   value = data.google_compute_instance.sql_instance
}

//Create boot disk snapshot
resource "google_compute_snapshot" "boot_snapshot" {
 name        = var.boot_snapshot_name
 source_disk = var.boot_disk_name
 zone        = var.zone
 storage_locations = [var.region]
}
```

But now I want to restore the snapshots to new volumes. I've been googling around and I haven't found any answers that pertain to GCP.

How can I restore the snapshots I take using Terraform into a new volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try to create the new VM within the snapshot that you have created for the old VM.
First, you need to create a `google_compute_disk` with the snapshot that you had created, using the [snapshot parameter](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_disk#snapshot)
Then should create the VM with the `compute_instance` module, with the [bootDisk.source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#source) with the previous disk created